# How can I use a full-page gradient?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I am very new to web technologies and am just trying to complete a design with a full-page gradient. Color values are `rgba(8,32,62,50%) and rgba(85,124,147,50%)`. I am just unable to identify the angle from [Figma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figma_(software)) design. Here is the actual implementation of this color combination in the page.

I am sharing a screenshot below.

[image]

Here is what I have been doing.

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(8, 32, 62), rgba(85, 124, 147, 50%));
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly adjust the gradient value accordingly:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgb(20, 32, 47), rgb(85, 124, 147));
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff; /* Set text color to white or any readable color */
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Answer (score -1):

*I hope it will help you*.

To create a gradient in CSS with the colors `rgba(8,32,62,50%)` and `rgba(85,124,147,50%)`, you can use the following CSS code:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(8, 32, 62, 50%), rgba(85, 124, 147, 50%));
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;  /* Set text color to white or any readable color */
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

In this code, **linear-gradient** is used to create a gradient background. The **to right** bottom specifies the direction of the gradient. You can adjust the direction based on your Figma design.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I still could not get the required result. The gradient is implemented full page.

Comment: Could you provide more details or specific examples of what you're encountering? This will help me better assist you in finding a solution.